# Adding EntityFramework.Extended to the project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've added `EntityFramework.Extended` ([link](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)) to my project using NuGet.
Now I'm facing one single problem; how can I use it's `Update` function with my `dbContext`?

Comment: they have some examples on the same page: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Comment: I've already seen that, but this does not help me in any way to understand how can I add/extend the methods to the dbContext as they did.
Am I missing anything or I lack some knowledge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import namespace `using EntityFramework.Extensions` and use `Update` (sample from Update method description):

```
dbContext.Users.Update(
         u => u.Email.EndsWith(emailDomain),
         u => new User { IsApproved = false, LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now });
```

Comment: Oww my.. I've tried that a million times, yet the Update method never appeared. #facepalm
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You specify Where predicate for Update like so:

```
context.tblToUpdate
       .Update(entry => condition, entryWithnewValues => new tblToUpdate{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update with:

```
YourDbContext context=new YourDbContext();
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.YourModels.Update(
    t => t.StatusId == 1, 
    t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});

//example of using an IQueryable as the filter for the update
var yourmodel = context.YourModels.Where(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
context.YourModels.Update(yourmodel , u => new YourModel {FirstName = "newfirstname"});
```

You should have a class that inherits DbContext and has public DbSets like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
    public class YourDBContext: DbContext
    {
         public DbSet<YourModel> YourModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Nothing special is required for using EntityFramework.Extended

Answer (score -1):

The Extensions methods on DbContext are now gone away.

The Extensions methods supported are only on IQueryable

[image]

Comment: This answer is not related to legacy *EntityFramework.Extended* library. It does not solve the problem described in the question. It might be a comment to the question. And why do you think that legacy extensions supported DbContext? `dbContext.Users.Update` is not a DbContext extension