# Best way to update a single property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following code in my application

```
using (ApplicationDbContext ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
     Instance i = ctx.Instance.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
     i.Views++;
     ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there a more Efficient way to achieve this? or is EF smart enough to realize whats going on and generate a simple update statement rather than running a select then update?

Any help would be great or guidance on how this should work.

Comment: Side note: This code can throw `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Could have a look at https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended  Allows straight updates, but be careful as it commits the changes immediately, not on save changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, EF is not smart enough to do both things in one run.

I tried it out with a simple model and watched what happens in the profiler.
In an example like yours EF will first get the record with a `SELECT` and then run `exec sp_executesql` with the desired `UPDATE`.

Unfortunately I am pretty sure you cannot get EF to do this in a more intelligent way.

Even if you shorten your code to be:

```
Instance i = ctx.Instance.First(s => s.Id == id).Views++;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

It will still do it in a separate `SELECT` and `UPDATE`.

I think that is just the price you pay for not accessing the database with `SQL` directly.

As pointed out by Sriram Sakthivel and also in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20624826/2186023) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962489/2186023) you can use the [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/tree/master/Source) (also available via nuget) to do it in one run, you do not need `SaveChanges()` any more then.

Just add the package to the project and

`using EntityFramework.Extensions;`

to the file where you want to use it, then you can do your update in one run like this:

```
ctx.Instance.Update(i => i.Id == id, i => new Instance() { Views= i.Views + 1 });
```

In the raw SQL that is then sent to your DBMS it will look something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Instance] SET 
[Views] = [Views] + 1  
FROM [dbo].[Instance] AS j0 INNER JOIN (
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Instance] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[Id]
) AS j1 ON (j0.[Id] = j1.[Id])
```

Not entirely beautiful but still better than two seperate statements, heh :)?

Comment: Ah, That is a shame really.. this is quite a common scenario and you would think this would be smarter OR a separate method for doing this!

Comment: @Steoates, @Thewads I now also included information about `EntityFramework.Extended` in my answer